# AWS EB with Docker, Node and Nginx Config Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

On AWS, I have configured Elastic BeanStalk to deploy multiple EC2 instances running a Dockerized Node app behind a Elastic Load Balancer. In addition, I have AWS Certificate manager working and loading the site over https via SSL. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. Automatically redirect non www to www.domain.com
2. Automatically redirect http to https

I am trying to use NGINX to accomplish this, and I want to process to be automated so that new instances that are spun up via the scaling rules, includes this configuration automatically.

After some research, I found that some people were accomplishing this via a .ebextensions/nginx.config file in the project root.

Here is my nginx override config file:

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/sites-available/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
              default        "upgrade";
              ""            "";
          }
          server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;

          }

          server {
              listen 443 ssl;

            gzip on;
            gzip_comp_level 4;
            gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

              if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
                  set $year $1;
                  set $month $2;
                  set $day $3;
                  set $hour $4;
              }
              access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

              access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

              location / {
                  proxy_pass            http://docker;
                  proxy_http_version    1.1;

                  proxy_set_header    Connection            $connection_upgrade;
                  proxy_set_header    Upgrade                $http_upgrade;
                  proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
                  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              }
          }
```

The node app is running in the docker container on port 3000 and that port is exposed.

Four questions:

1. Is this the right way to do this with AWS?
2. Is this nginx config file correct (to redirect to www and https)?
3. Do I need another SSL Certificate here in the NGINX config? I have one at the domain level using AWS Certification Manger
4. Will a redirect screw up health checks and kill auto deployments?

Of course, the biggest issue is that I cannot get AWS to accept this configuration. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a much easier way using AWS built in functionality that would simplify your Nginx config considerably.

**Certificates**

With AWS Certificate Manager you would load the cert onto the ELB as part of its configuration, and not your EC2 instances.

[ACM SSL Certificates for Elastic Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html)

---

**Redirecting Apex Domain / SSL**

For redirection, use an **alias** redirect in Route53  `www` to the ELB in DNS. ELBs contain redirecting `http` to `https` in its configuration. Note that `http(s)://yourdomain.com` (no `www` or subdomain) is called the APEX domain, and has some restrictions. Using an `alias` to an ELB is a supported method of redirection in AWS.

> Q. Can I point my zone apex (example.com versus www.example.com) at my Elastic Load Balancer?
>
> Yes. Amazon Route 53 offers a special type of record called an ‘Alias’ record that lets you map your zone apex (example.com) DNS name to your ELB DNS name (i.e. elb1234.elb.amazonaws.com). IP addresses associated with Amazon Elastic Load Balancers can change at any time due to scaling up, scaling down, or software updates. Route 53 responds to each request for an Alias record with one or more IP addresses for the load balancer. Queries to Alias records that are mapped to ELB load balancers are free. These queries are listed as “Intra-AWS-DNS-Queries” on the Amazon Route 53 usage report.

[Amazon Route 53 FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am already use the AWS Certificate Manager and Route 53. I have an A record to an ELB alias, and I have a CNAME set up for the non-www to www of my domain, but this isn't auto-redirecting, and I don't see an option in Route 53 to actually redirect the user. The DNS is resolving correctly, but the URL isn't actually changing, which is what I want. Am I missing some config option in Route 53 to do this?

Comment: If you're already using Route 53, you can use their proprietary alias "record" to solve this problem. With standard DNS, you cannot do this at all and you have to have a web site send a 301 redirect. Of course, you still need to send the 301 redirects or deal with the fact that some requests will come in without the www.

Probably the easiest way to do this is to set up an S3 bucket with the name of the naked domain and configure the bucket properties to redirect from example.com to www.example.com, and then in Route 53 create an alias for the naked domain name that points to that S3 bucket.